# Struggling to understand why float() is giving this error

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

Here is a piece of the dataset:

```
18,8,307,130,3504,12,70,1,chevrolet
15,8,350,165,3693,11.5,70,1,buick
18,8,318,150,3436,11,70,1,plymouth
16,8,304,150,3433,12,70,1,amc
17,8,302,140,3449,10.5,70,1,ford
15,8,429,198,4341,10,70,1,ford
14,8,454,220,4354,9,70,1,chevrolet
14,8,440,215,4312,8.5,70,1,plymouth
```

Here is the code:

```
data = sc.textFile("hw6/auto_mpg_original.csv")
records = data.map(lambda x: x.split(","))

hp = float(records.map(lambda x: x[3]))
disp = np.array(float(records.map(lambda x: x[2])))

final_data_1 = LabeledPoint(hp, disp)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloudera/Desktop/hw6.py", line 41, in <module>
    hp = float(records.map(lambda x: x[3]))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

This seems basic, but i'm really having trouble tracking down a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the type of `records.map()` probably an `RDD`. You can apply the `float()` in the `map()`, e.g.:

```
hp = records.map(lambda x: float(x[3]))
```

But you will need to `.collect()` the results before using it, e.g.:

```
hp = records.map(lambda x: float(x[3])).collect()
disp = np.array(records.map(lambda x: float(x[2])).collect())
```

Comment: i'm getting the same error after making those changes.

Comment: Odd, so I commented out the LabeledPoint line and then the code runs fine. This function is really causing me problems. I'm having troubles understanding why it works and doesnt.

Comment: I would be surprised if you got the same error on the same line, because any spark errors would be very different, and moving the `float()` into the map would make it is a spark error.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation. Do you have any ideas why LabeledPoint would cause this error?

Comment: Without seeing the error, it's hard to diagnose - perhaps update your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the input from the CSV, the column is either empty or containing non numeric value

Comment: as an RDD, they do come in as strings but that is why I'm converting them into floats. All of the values are numeric though, i've uploaded a piece of the dataset

Comment: You need to check the whole dataset and not just a piece of it. There is some dirty value causing this error

Comment: You can't `float(<RDD>)`, nothing wrong with the dataset.

Comment: @Sarvex the dataset is fine, i've cleaned it